# How to use the package latex-wordcount on Atom?

Tags: texcount

I have a Windows machine with StrawberryPerl installed. I downloaded the texcount Perl script and have placed it in the PATH variable. I have also installed the latex-wordcount package for Atom.

However, what I don't understand is how to actually use the package after installing?

Currently, I am left with no choice but to use the texcount online service.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Atom or the latex-wordcount package: I suppose you've checked the web page https://atom.io/packages/latex-wordcount. For TeXcount, you should start checking if you can run it on the command line: eg `texcount --version` or `texcount.pl --version` (which may end up being different copies/versions if your TeX installation already has TeXcount installed). Maybe you have to run `perl [texcount-path]` if the `.pl` has not been set up. Once you have TeXcount running, you can try getting the Atom package to work. If you have problems, describe what you have tried.

Comment: @EinarRødland Yep, I checked that webpage of course! It gives a description of the commands, but doesn't elaborate on how/where to execute the commands themselves. texcount works just fine from the command line. I would prefer the word count being shown in the editor itself, if possible.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't be of much help, not being familiary with Atom. Judging by the script, it looks like it's supposed to set up commands `latex-wordcount::...` in the command palette (ctrl+shift+P perhaps?). Hopefully, someone familiar with Atom will come along...

Comment: @EinarRødland Whoa that actually works. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: @ArnavVarshney Since you've found an answer, and Einar isn't really familiar with Atom, could you add an answer explaining in detail what you did. This will help other users who find your question.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing the package in Atom, pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P` (Windows) opens up the Command Palette on Atom. In this window, type "Latex" to show a whole bunch of Latex Wordcount commands (see image below for reference).

[image: Command Palette in Atom]

Choosing the appropriate option, and pressing Enter presents the word count in a popup window.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Thanks for adding the answer!